# SVG not appearing in screenshot

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have followed the tutorial here: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/create-pushpin-markup-svg

I have succesfully implemented svg images as part of my viewer, have them tied into redraw on viewer events, etc. But I then went to use the screenshot ability of the viewer. This resulted in getting a screenshot without the svg markup.

However markups such as lines that where drawn are working, as they are added to the overlay (overlayscenes).

Is there a way to add the svg images to the viewers overlay so that they can be exported into the screenshot or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround would be to use the [canvg library](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/) to draw the svgs to the shot after it's captured (by a screen-to-canvas rendering library such as [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) etc.):

```
html2canvas(viewer.canvas).then(canvas => {
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawSvg(SVG_XML_OR_PATH) //draw the markups here with the extension enabled by "canvg"
    canvas.toDataURL/toBlob ... //persist your capture

});
```

Comment: is there no way to add an SVG image into a scene?